# Can you add an address for an Amazon Cart via API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-product-api

I cant see it in the Product Advertising API [reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/CartCreate.html) but I wonder if it's possible to dynamically / automatically set the delivery billing address (and possibly further options like if the billing should be sent or the product should be wrapped as a gift) for an Amazon cart?

If that would be possible but not via Product Advertising API it would be fine, too (e.g. buying things for yourself with an API).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand - no, you can't.

From the Amazon:

> Amazon hosts the web pages in the Order Pipeline. Your application plays **no role** in purchasing the items or order fulfillment. However, your application must use the `PurchaseURL` returned by Product Advertising API cart operations to add the shopping cart items to the Order Pipeline.

Order Pipeline in docs is

> A series of Amazon web pages that guides the customer through the checkout process, which includes adding the customer's name, `shipping and billing addresses`, payment method, and a purchase confirmation web page, as shown in the following.

That's mean users should fill `shipping and billing addresses` on Amazon hosted web pages during the checkout process. You can only provider url to finish checkout.

Same thing with your own address. There is no API to change it.