# Is there an amazon API or SDK available to be able to add addresses in your own account?

Tags: amazon-product-api, aws-api-gateway

I am looking for a programmatic way to add address to my amazon account.
Normally done through Your Account > You Addresses > Add New Address process.

Can you please help me.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37748936/can-you-add-an-address-for-an-amazon-cart-via-api this might be helpful to you